# opening local html file in android web browser and it should persist till I don't close tab

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am using android 10 with google chrome 104.0.5112.69.
I think that my question will also be relevant for newer android OS or newer google chrome.
I have an html file (15aug-951am.html) in my download folder. You can assume that my html file has input text box and some javascript that processes it.
Here is an example (save it as 15aug-951am.html)
[code]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>record input in history with time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="text_box" value="" STYLE="width:350px;" placeholder="enter words then press Submit to get recorded in history">
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="submit_btn"  onclick="add_to_history()">Submit</button>
        <div  id="history_list">
            <h3>History</h3>
            <ol id="history_ol">
            </ol>
        </div>
        <script>
            function add_to_history()
            {
                const node = document.createElement("li");
                var curr_time= new Date();
                var user_input=document.getElementById("text_box").value;
                var list_item=user_input+' at '+curr_time;
                const textnode = document.createTextNode(list_item);
                node.appendChild(textnode);
                document.getElementById("history_ol").appendChild(node);    
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[/code]

My aim is to maintain data entered in html for long time.
To open my file in a tab in google chrome.
(1)If I open it using downloads app 
[First](https://ibb.co/FYK9QC1)
[Second](https://ibb.co/NCqSc3J)
[Third](https://ibb.co/vQLBKcW)
then I get following URL in chrome
content://com.android.providers.downloads.ui.fileprovider/root_files_storage/emulated/0/Download/15aug-951am.html
(2)If I open it using file manager app then I get following URL in chrome
content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/Download/15aug-951am.html
The problem with these is that they become inaccessible after few days ( [for 1](https://postimg.cc/gx67Tj0p) ,  [for 2](https://postimg.cc/kBHZsKqw) ). Then I close the tab and open html file again using app.
Also, I noticed that my web page refreshes after few hours. To verify, I used HTML containing following data.
[code]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>update time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" id="get date and time"  onclick="gettime()">get date and time</button>
        <p id="today"></p>
        <script>
            window.onload=init;

            function init()
            {
                var today = new Date();
                document.getElementById("today").innerHTML="started at "+today;
            }

            function gettime()
            {
                var today = new Date();
                var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
                var curr_content=document.getElementById("today").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("today").innerHTML=curr_content+"<br>clicked at "+time;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[/code]

Que 1 )I am hoping that using cookies I can restore data I had entered in my html file so that web page refresh has no effect. Will that work ?

Que 2 )I have no idea on how to deal with URL becoming unavailable after few days.

Is it possible to keep local html file open in google chrome until I close tab ?

Thanks.

PS: here persist means that I want to avoid web page refreshing after few hours (if possible) and definitely overcome web page becoming inaccesible after few days .
I have added error screenshots on 18 august 23:03 GMT .

Comment: If they become inaccessable after time then first make a copy and then your app should use FileProvider to serve to Chrome. Did you test such?

Comment: Your html source does not contain a form. How should we test this?

Comment: Chrome does not close tabs self. Never saw such.

Comment: `open it using downloads app` ? No idea what you are doing.

Comment: `.... should persist till I don't close tab`? You mean: until i close the tab.

Comment: Please make them clickable links as now they are only urls.

Comment: I have added screenshots to show how downloads app is used to open html file downloaded via gmail app . Also I have added simple html code you can try. I will add inaccessible screenshot too as soon as it happens again in my mobile .

Comment: Created the two files and placed in Android devices. With my own app and FileProvider i serve the files to Chrome. They work. I think that problem `Que 2 )` will not come as the uri will be valid always. For the refreshing problem... well i need time...

Comment: On a device of mine Chrome did not refresh the page since yesterday.

Comment: I have 12 tabs open in google chrome . If I send google chrome app to background and open it after few hours then page refresh occurs which can be verified with my second html code  . After a day or two webpage becomes totally inaccessible .

Comment: @blackapps , can you share your app that serves file to chrome ?

Comment: In another device the page got refreshed after a time. So all is hopeless i think.

Comment: Thanks for your effort . I am wondering is there a way to message another user on stack overflow other than via comment on question page ?